# Unable to remove devtoolset-7 from my CentOS System

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, uninstall

I am trying to remove devtoolset-7 from my CentOS system. For this I am running following commands:-

```
sudo yum remove devtoolset-7
sudo yum remove devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel
sudo yum remove devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel
```

After running these commands, I list out devtools by command:-

```
sudo yum list | grep devtoolset-7*
```

devtoolset-7 is still present in there. here is the list I got:-

```
devtoolset-7.x86_64                        7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-all.x86_64                    7.0-5.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-binutils.x86_64               2.28-11.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-binutils-devel.x86_64         2.28-11.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-build.x86_64                  7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dockerfiles.x86_64            7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dwz.x86_64                    0.12-1.1.el7           centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dyninst.x86_64                9.3.2-3.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dyninst-devel.x86_64          9.3.2-3.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dyninst-doc.x86_64            9.3.2-3.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dyninst-static.x86_64         9.3.2-3.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-dyninst-testsuite.x86_64      9.3.2-3.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-elfutils.x86_64               0.170-5.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-elfutils-devel.x86_64         0.170-5.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-elfutils-libelf.x86_64        0.170-5.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-elfutils-libelf-devel.x86_64  0.170-5.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-elfutils-libs.x86_64          0.170-5.el7            centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gcc.x86_64                    7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++.x86_64                7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gcc-gdb-plugin.x86_64         7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran.x86_64           7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gcc-plugin-devel.x86_64       7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gdb.x86_64                    8.0.1-36.el7           centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gdb-doc.noarch                8.0.1-36.el7           centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-gdb-gdbserver.x86_64          8.0.1-36.el7           centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-go.x86_64                     7.0-5.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libasan-devel.x86_64          7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libatomic-devel.x86_64        7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libcilkrts-devel.x86_64       7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libgccjit.x86_64              7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libgccjit-devel.x86_64        7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libgccjit-docs.x86_64         7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libitm-devel.x86_64           7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-liblsan-devel.x86_64          7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libmpx-devel.x86_64           7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libquadmath-devel.x86_64      7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel.x86_64        7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-docs.x86_64         7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libtsan-devel.x86_64          7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-libubsan-devel.x86_64         7.3.1-5.15.el7         centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-llvm.x86_64                   7.0-5.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-ltrace.x86_64                 0.7.91-2.el7           centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-make.x86_64                   1:4.2.1-3.el7          centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-memstomp.x86_64               0.1.5-5.1.el7          centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-oprofile.x86_64               1.2.0-2.el7.1          centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-oprofile-devel.x86_64         1.2.0-2.el7.1          centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-oprofile-jit.x86_64           1.2.0-2.el7.1          centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-perftools.x86_64              7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-runtime.x86_64                7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-rust.x86_64                   7.0-5.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-strace.x86_64                 4.17-7.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap.x86_64              3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-client.x86_64       3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-devel.x86_64        3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-initscript.x86_64   3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-runtime.x86_64      3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-sdt-devel.x86_64    3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-server.x86_64       3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-systemtap-testsuite.x86_64    3.1-4s.el7             centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-toolchain.x86_64              7.1-4.el7              centos-sclo-rh
devtoolset-7-valgrind.x86_64               1:3.13.0-11.el7        centos-sclo-rh
```

Please tell me right way to remove devtoolset-7.

Comment: The easy way to identify installed packages is : `$ rpm -qa | grep devtoolset-7`

Comment: Isn't asterisk required? `sudo yum remove devtoolset-7\*` https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/packaging_guide/sect-uninstalling_a_software_collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've fallen into the "default" trap; `yum list` will (from `man yum`, under "List Options"):

> List all **available** and installed packages.

My emphasis on **available**. If you only want to see the packages that you have currently installed, use:

```
yum list installed
```

Additionally, be careful with constructs like:

```
sudo yum list | grep devtoolset-7*
```

As your shell will attempt to expand `devtoolset-7*` as a wildcard and could potentially match one or more filenames in your current directory, confusing your results. Instead, `yum` can take a wildcard to search for:

```
sudo yum list installed 'devtoolset-7*'
```

(Notice the single quotes protecting the wildcard from the shell).